# Entity framework can't switch connection in Integration test

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, integration-testing

I have a normal project where the connection is nicely configured in the app.config. And I have a test project where the connection is also nicely configured. This all works perfectly.

But when I want to switch connection in code, nothing seems to work. It seems to completely ignore the connection string I pass in the constructor, and it keeps using the default connection (as specified by the config which matches the classname of the db context.

My configuration in my test project:

```
<!-- Connection string  -->
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyApplication.Database.MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDBFilename=C:\DB\Test1.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="TestEntities" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDBFilename=C:\DB\Test2.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

And my (still) small test:

```
using (var db = new MyContext(@"name=TestEntities"))
{
    db.Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

What this does is create a new database at C:\DB\Test1.mdf and not C:\DB\Test2.mdf. Which is weird because if I remove the connection string I get an error that it can't be found. And if I debug the test I can even see the correct connection string within the connection object.

I have no clue what i'm doing wrong here.

What works (but is a bit weird/ugly), is to subclass my DatabaseContext so it gets a new name.

P.S. This is my entire app.config file (in test project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>


  <!-- Connection string  -->
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyApplication.Database.MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDBFilename=C:\DB\Test1.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="TestEntities" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDBFilename=C:\DB\Test2.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Comment: You should consider subclassing because it will be easier just to instantiate a new context without having to pass in the string everywhere in your code. It'll also work better with migrations and adding different db entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your entire app.config. TestEntities connection  string does not exist. Check  '+ TestEntities' in the config

Edit:

Also, if the context class name has a connection string with the same name defined in the config- This will take precedence. Manual connection string definitions will be ignored.

Please search for 'using the existing connectionstring' in this link : https://books.google.co.za/books?id=X63NBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA157&lpg=PA157&dq=entity+framework+connection+string+precedence&source=bl&ots=ZjPMWaidLV&sig=zmo40T5myWllmNzlVI8rS25-tXo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RkCQVfjuJ-OP7AbuoKu4CQ&ved=0CCsQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=entity%20framework%20connection%20string%20precedence&f=false

Comment: I updated the file to correspond to my initial test (i accedentially updated it with a newer version).

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link. Please check if this helps

Comment: No way! That would explain a lot. Now i get an exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot open database "MyApplication.Database.MyContext".  At least i get an error now, that should be easier to fix. :)

Answer (score 0):

Without more code I can only guess but I suspect you are missing the call to the baseclass constructor. It should be something like this:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }
}
```

Comment: Good tip, but no sigar. If i remove the TestEntities connection string from the config I would get an error. So the connection string is used/checked.

Comment: What happens if you change new MyContext(@"name=TestEntities") to new MyContext(@"TestEntities")? That's how I always write it

Comment: That didn't do anything for me. Also no error when TestEntities intentionally spelled wrong.